# c# reproduce datetime from ticks

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a datetime field like

```
{01/01/0001 00:01:02}
```

Millisecond = 30 and the Ticks for the above datetime field is

```
6203000000
```

The ticks save in the database as an int value which is 62030. I need to reproduce the above date time using the value in the database (62030). So I tried the following.

```
var data = 62030;
winTime = new DateTime().AddTicks(Convert.ToInt64(data.ToString().PadRight(10, '0')));
var b = winTime.Ticks;
```

var b = 6203000000. But it returns minute as 10 instead 01, second as 20 instead of 02 and Millisecond as 300 instead of 030.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is very confusing at the moment - it's not clear why you'd use string conversions at all, and the given date/time doesn't have "ticks 62030" - it has "ticks 6203000000" as specified previously. Did you mean "milliseconds 62030"?

Comment: updated. Hope now it make more sense

Comment: In math, padding a number on the right with `K` zeros is done by multiplying the number by the `K`-th power of ten.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to me that your "ticks 62030" is actually "milliseconds 62030" in which case it's very simple - you just need to multiply by "the number of ticks per millisecond" which is 10,000. You don't need to use `DateTime` for this at all:

```
// Note that if you want any significant length of time, you'd expect to get
// the data as a long, not an int
int data = 62030; // Milliseconds
long ticks = data * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
```

... and you *certainly* don't need string conversions. Converting to a string, padding, and then converting back again is a very tortuous and error-prone way of performing multiplication.

Or if you *do* need a `DateTime`:

```
int data = 62030; // Milliseconds
long dateTime = new DateTime(data * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);
```

I strongly suspect that any `DateTime` value that early should *actually* be treated as a `TimeSpan` though - what's this really meant to represent? If so, it's even easier:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(data);
```

Date and time concepts are very easy to mix up, and you end up with some very subtle bugs. Personally I'd recommend using my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) project which separates them more than .NET does, but even if you don't use the library it's worth looking at the [list of concepts](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.1.x/docs/userguide/concepts.html) so you can think about them appropriately within .NET too.

Comment: Even Jon Skeet is using `var` all the time! Am I old-fashioned for typing my variables??

Comment: @ElRonnoco Only in cases where it's obvious, I'd hazard to say.

Comment: @ElRonnoco: I did it here just because the OP did. I'd normally explicitly type integer literals.

Comment: @GrantThomas Well `data = 62030` - is that `Int16`, `Int32` or `Int64`? If you had an overloaded constructor that behaved differently given the specific type then it would be important. I'm frightened by this brave new world!

Comment: @ElRonnoco: You're right to be concerned. (It's an Int32 in this case.) Will edit my answer to make you less scared ;)

Comment: Yes Jon Skeet, you're right, it's actually milliseconds. Don't know why .Net shows it as Ticks and shows 30 as milliseconds. Anyway Thanks a lot.

Comment: Consider using `TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond` instead of something like `1000 * 10_000L`.  It's self documenting and helps keep the units straight

Comment: @Flydog57: Well, TicksPerMillisecond in this case, but yes, done.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use the `DateTime` constructor that accepts an `Int64` representing ticks, such that:

```
var dateTimeFromTicks = new DateTime(ticks);
```

Comment: Just tried that and it returned {01/01/0001 00:10:20} as the value

Answer (score 0):

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /* read datetime now */
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        dt = DateTime.Now;
        
        /* datetime convert to tick */
        long TickeringTick = dt.Ticks;
        Console.WriteLine("Date time now -> " + dt.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff"));
        Console.WriteLine("Converted to Ticks = " + TickeringTick.ToString());

        /* convert tick to datetime */
        long myTicks = TickeringTick;
        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(myTicks);
        Console.WriteLine("Date from ticks :" + dt.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff"));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```